# Error while generating node info file with database.runMigration

Tags: postgresql, corda

I added `database.runMigration: true` to my build.gradle file but I'm getting this error when running deployNodes. What's causing this?

```
[ERROR] 14:05:21+0200 [main] subcommands.ValidateConfigurationCli.logConfigurationErrors$node - Error(s) while parsing node configuration:
        - for path: "database.runMigration": Unknown property 'runMigration'
```

Here's my build.gradle's deployNode task

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
    directory "./build/nodes"
    ext.drivers = ['.jdbc_driver']
    ext.extraConfig = [
            'dataSourceProperties.dataSourceClassName' : "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource",
            'dataSourceProperties.dataSource.user' : "corda",
            'dataSourceProperties.dataSource.password' : "corda1234",
            'database.transactionIsolationLevel' : 'READ_COMMITTED',
            'database.runMigration' : "true"
    ]
    nodeDefaults {
        projectCordapp {
            deploy = false
        }
        cordapp project(':cordapp-contracts-states')
        cordapp project(':cordapp')
    }
    node {
        name "O=HUS,L=Helsinki,C=FI"
        p2pPort 10008
        rpcSettings {
            address "localhost:10009"
            adminAddress "localhost:10049"
        }
        webPort 10017
        rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
        extraConfig = ext.extraConfig + [
                'dataSourceProperties.dataSource.url' :
                        "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hus_db?currentSchema=corda_schema"
        ]
        drivers = ext.drivers
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database.runMigration is a Corda Enterprise property only.
To control database migration in Corda Open Source use initialiseSchema.

initialiseSchema
Boolean which indicates whether to update the database schema at startup (or create the schema when node starts for the first time). If set to false on startup, the node will validate if it’s running against a compatible database schema.

Default: true

You may refer to the below link to look out for other database properties which you can set.

https://docs.corda.net/corda-configuration-file.html